# How to parse contents from a text file to add user and password in bash?

Tags: bash, unix

I need to add users in batch to suse11, and lower versions. I have a script that does it, but it's not parsing my file like it should, instead it adds a user and a password for each item on the text file.

I've tried using the newusers command but this farm of servers doesn't seem to have newusers as a bash module due to security reasons probably.

The content of my text file is "X Y" (meaning user and password), for each user i want to add, and this is how I'm reading the text file

```
for i in $(cat UserBase.txt); do
    useradd -p $i
    echo "User $i added successfully!"
    exec chpasswd $i:$i"123"
    echo "Password for user $i added successfully!"
    usermod -G $i wheel username
    echo "User $i added successfully to wheel!"
EOF
done
```

As I said, it adds a user for each item on the lines it read, meaning it adds a user for the usr and another user for the passwd,. which is exactly i don't need.

I need it to read X and Y like columns on a file and then discriminate between the first and second field so i can add it like user credentials in suse

EDIT: my text file format is

```
username_1 password_1
username_2 password_2
```

Comment: Please post sample contents of the file you're trying to read (no need for real passwords of course, just format).

Answer (score 2):

Hello the problem with your code is that if you run a for loop over the cat output it will iter over all items in the file it will turn

A B

C D

into

A B C D

So you should read the file line by line like:

```
while read user password;
do
    useradd -m -p $(openssl passwd -1 "$password") --groups wheel "$user"
done < UserBase.txt
```

Note: That I have put your user actions in one line also.

Hope this helps

Comment: (1) Replace `read line` with `read user password` and then the rest of the code will simplify.  (2) So that pathname expansion, etc, don't cause havoc with your commands, place  references to shell variables inside double-quotes, e.g. `useradd -m -p $(openssl passwd -1 "$password") --groups wheel "$user"`

Comment: @John1024 NIce. Thanks a lot. I have edited my answer with your suggestions.